# How to take out ageing of two rows in access right from vb6.0 code

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I have designed database in access and program is designed in vb6.0 but problem is I have two rows in table 
Expiry date and today's date 
I want ageing days to change everyday automatically by writting code in main window of program to show it on mshflexgrid. Like I have written a code to get change the today's date to be updated automatically everyday as I will not know no. of rows in table in same way I need code for ageing. 
Code for today's date is:

```
Dim smt As String
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
If rs.State = 1 Then rs.Close
smt = "update bgentry set today ='" & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "'"
rs.Open smt, cn, adOpenStatic
```

bgentry.today = bgentry is name of table and today is name of field in table to show a today's date.

Sample data is when main window of program will get focus:

In the existing table called bgentry today and age all the datas of this two column should be modified automatically by code. For example:

```
Expiring Date Today's Date Age
19/02/15      20/02/15     1
```

Expiring date will be added by user every day but today's date and age should be changed everyday in the database so that this report can be shown in mshflexgrid.

Comment: show us what the sample data should be before and after your process

Comment: It has been defined as date/time